# Schengen visa refusal: Consequences?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

If my application for a visa got refused by Poland's embassy and I applied from the Hungarian embassy after changing my passport and passport number, will Hungary's embassy know that I got refused in Poland before?

And if they know, will it will be recorded for all my life or does it go down after some time? And must I get a visa from Poland first?

Comment: What are your travel plans and why were you refused?  In principle, visa applications are stored in a central database, so Hungary should know what Poland has done, even if you get a new passport.

Comment: Did you read my answer to your other questions? You won't be refused “because you were nervous” but everything you wrote suggested you lied about the purpose of your trip and tried to obtain a visa fraudulently. That's a very serious reason to refuse a visa and you won't get meaningful answer if you don't explain the situation.

Comment: It seems to me you are approaching this all wrong and digging you further into a hole. The more you try to cheat, the more dangerous it is and the less likely you are to get a visa in the end.

Comment: Not clear why you are asking here.  If you have ignored everything up to this point, does it really make sense to see us as a worthwhile resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refusals (and issued visa) are recorded in a database called the Visa Information System, [for five years](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system/index_en.htm). Hungary will know about it but is free to make its decision independently, they don't have to ask Poland for permission and there is no reason for you to apply there first.

If you change your passport before it expires, not only will they still know that you were refused a visa (based on your name and date/place of birth or, possibly, your biometrics) but they will also notice you tried some deception tactics and that could weigh heavily against you.

Also, they will obviously know about the grounds for the refusal. Failure to adequately document your financial means for example would not be too bad if you remedied the situation in the meantime. But fraud would be very bad, no matter what you do afterwards.

---

For completeness, note that there is also another database called the Schengen Information System with completely different rules (you won't end up in there merely because an application was refused but only for more serious violations).

If there is a notice about you in the SIS, you have to contact the country that put a notice in the database and appeal the ban to (have a chance to) get a visa. A visa application cannot override such a ban and, legally speaking, another country can, at most, issue a “limited territorial validity” visa but not a Schengen visa (and, mostly, they will issue nothing, it's very easy for them: just a box to check without any further verification or need to justify anything).

Entries in the SIS have various automatic expiration delays but I think that a country can always reactivate an entry to keep it in the database as long as they wish, based on their national rules.

Comment: +1, and take note that the OP has previous threads that lead in to this one.

Comment: @Relaxed thank your for your help , other small question please , if i apply for a visit visa they must call the host family 100 % , or they may not call them ??

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif Stop asking how to cheat, I don't know and it will get you in trouble. If you have a genuine invitation, it does not matter what they might do.